# .Find Optimal/Best Practice way to read several items from a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've read that operation going back and forth from the workbook can be intensive. And where possible try to read what you need from a worksheet and then do the operations you require from there. Here is an excerpt from code I have, and I'm wondering if there's a best practice way to do the following, or if what I've done is the way it should be done.

```
CI = Sheets(OperatingCostsSheet).Range("B5:B8").Find(WHAT:=LOB, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 1)
CC = Sheets(OperatingCostsSheet).Range("B5:B8").Find(WHAT:=LOB, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 4)
OS = Sheets(OperatingCostsSheet).Range("B5:B8").Find(WHAT:=LOB, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 5)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would even notice a difference between location methods within 4 cells but you should probably record the position of the first find and use that for subsequent offset assignments. Your current .Find-based code has no error control on no match/find.

```
dim i as variant
with Sheets(OperatingCostsSheet).Range("B5:B8")
    i = application.match(LOB, .cells, 0)  'same as .find with matchcase:=false; returns matching position within B5:B8; e.g. 1 to 4.
    if not iserror(i) then
        CI = .cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1)
        CC = .cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 4)
        OS = .cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 5)
    end if
end with
```